# Signed Extension validate len parameter

Tags: polkadot-js, signed-extensions

How is the len parameter of the Signed Extension validation function computed?

I tried computing the length with PolkadotJS by getting the length of the encoded call but that does not seem to be the same as the length that is being passed into the validate parameter.

I am guessing the length is not the length of the Call function since an additional parameter is passed instead of getting it from the Call function.

[SigneExtension](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a200cdb93c6af5763b9c7bf313fa708764ac88ca/primitives/runtime/src/traits.rs#L725C3-L725C3)